# Dashclock extension: Aligning expanded body text to form a table

Tags: android, string-formatting, dashclock

I am unable to align text in a table format in my dashclock extension's body. Following is the format I want (first column left aligned, rest columns right aligned):

```
   A               2               3
   BC              5              10
   DEF            22               3
```

In the code I try aligning the following way

```
String.format("%-10s %10s %10s\n", val1, val2, val3);
```

When I log the result of the above formatting it prints in the correct and intended way in logcat. But when I deploy the app and run it as part of the dashclock application, the alignment is completely off. The alignment when displayed in dashclock extension looks like:

```
   A           2               3
   BC            5              10
   DEF            22               3
```

I tried searching and looking into the `DashClockExtension` class to see if something is possible but couldn't. Also the `expandedBody` method in `ExtensionData` does not take SpannedString as argument, only `String`.

Any ideas as how to get the alignment right in the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to do this because the font used for displaying expanded body content isn't a monospace font, meaning each character has a different width. Feel free to file a feature request for representing tabular data though! http://dashclock.com/issues

Comment: Okay. Will it make much more sense to file the feature request for html support in expanded body text instead of just tabular data?

Comment: Hm, supporting full HTML in the widget is likely not possible, but monochrome or otherwise tabular data *may* be possible, depending on how important/broad the use case is.